# what's the mean of the code about btrace

Tags: java, btrace

In the following code:

```
import static com.sun.btrace.BTraceUtils.*;
import com.sun.btrace.annotations.*;
import org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo; 

@BTrace public class Trace{
   @OnMethod(
      clazz="org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer",
      method="parseDocument"
   )
   public static void traceExecute(DeploymentInfo di){
      printFields(di);
   }

   @OnMethod(
      clazz="java.net.URL",
      method="openConnection",
      location=@Location(Kind.RETURN)
   )
   public static void resolveEntity(@Self Object instance){
     String protocol = str(get(field("java.net.URL", "protocol"),instance));
     String file = str(get(field("java.net.URL", "file"),instance));
     if(startsWith(protocol,"http") && (endsWith(file,".xsd") || endsWith(file,".dtd"))){
        String authority = str(get(field("java.net.URL", "authority"),instance));
        String path = str(get(field("java.net.URL", "path"),instance));
        println("=====================================");
        print(protocol);
        print("://");
        print(authority);
        print(path);
        println(" not found!");
        println("who call:");
        jstack();
     }
   }
}
```

What does this mean: `get(field("java.net.URL", "authority"),instance)` ?

Please refer me to the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`field("java.net.URL", "authority")` will safely retrieve the field named **authority** from the class **java.net.URL**

`get(field, instance)` reflectively obtains the value of the given *field* in specified *instance*.

The [Javadoc for BTraceUtils](https://btrace.kenai.com/javadoc/1.2/com/sun/btrace/BTraceUtils.html) is a good starting point.